No internet with the default switch in hyper v
I can ping VMs from host (windows 10 pro), but not from VMs (Windows 10, Linux) to host or internet. I don't wanted to create an external switch because I want the isolation the default switch offers with nat. Anyway, what could be wrong?
Something obviously went wrong in the setup process, as I've done nothing but create a Hyper-V VM in management console and booted it up, didn't change any networking settings. I checked in both my linux and windows VMs, so this is not os-related also.

@John My host uses an ethernet connection to the router. Default switch is automatically internal with NAT, VLAN is unchecked.
